# QTAgent32.exe probes undesired path resulting into failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, specflow, .net-remoting

I have specflow based tests where I do following

```
[TestInit]
Init()
{
          set Remoting CallContext using CallContext.SetData()
          Initialize the EF model
}

[TestCleanup]
Cleanup()
{
         Dispose the EF mode
         Set the callcontext data item to null
}
```

When i execute the test in debug or run mode all my test code finished properly including the cleanup 
However after cleanup QTAgent32.exe looks up for one of my asseblies in 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE and obviously doesnt find it there since all my assemblies in Out directory of tests.
I dont want to copy my Dlls to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE or Private Assemblies/Public Assemblies folder
Is there any way to fix it?  Why is QTAgent32 is unaware of my Out directory..

Here is how actual code looks like

```
    public static void BeforeFeature()
    {

    }

    [AfterFeature]
    public static void AfterFeature()
    {   
        CallContext.SetData("SomeItems", null);
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        Model = new EFContainer();
        CallContext.SetData("SomeItems", somevalue);

    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        Model.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but the issue mentioned below https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81814766-a522-4a19-8575-7bc7f581623c/assembly-not-found-serialization-exception?forum=vststest          is still valid ? even with VS 2010?

Comment: can you provide a small reproduction project in a github repository that allows this issue to be replicated, then it could be investigated